# How to writing a function in Python to call another function while only assigning value to some arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Or equivalently, to pass multiple arguments to a called function?

So I am trying to do:

1. define a function `fun1`
2. define another function `fun2`, which will call `fun1` but only assigning some values to `fun1`, with other values being assigned otherwise; or maybe I can assign multiple arguments to a called function?

```
def fun1(x, y):
    return x*y

def fun2(fun, x):
    print(fun(x))

fun2(fun1(y=2), 3) # doesn't work
fun2(fun1, (3, 2)) # doesn't work either
```

So how should I do this? I want `fun2` to just print `fun1`'s result with some variable for `x` (here I choose it to be 3) and assigned(fixed) `y=2`

Comment: In fun2 write `f(*x)` instead of `f(x)`.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @kaya3
Use python's variable *args feature.

IDLE :

```
>>> def fun1(x, y):
        return x * y

>>> def fun2(fun, x):
        print(fun(*x))


>>> fun2(fun1, (3, 2))
6
```

Comment: thanks so basically to pass multiple arguments together as a tuple

Comment: just a bit further, can I pass `x` be a named tuple in `fun2` here? so I can arrange the order of arguments myself?

Comment: @coding_guy yes, you can do that

Comment: Bother with an example on how to do the named tuple thing?

Comment: fun2(x = (3, 2), fun = fun1 )

Comment: I mean with named tuple...